# Is there a word for these two different concepts of probability?

Tags: probability

I'm not a statistician or a mathematician. So I don't have the vocabulary to describe this concept.

There seems to be a difference between two different types of probability. For example, there is the kind they use in forecast models and the kind the use with more concrete percentages like dice.

If you tell me that "Dice have a 16.7% chance to roll a 1". I can test that statement to whatever confidence level I like.

But if you tell me that "There is a 20% chance of rain" or "There is a 45% chance Bill will be president" based on a model, I can't test that.

Is there a word for this difference? Am I correctly thinking about this?

Comment: "I can test that statement to whatever confidence level I like". How do you define a confidence level then?

Comment: @chl I guess what I mean is that I can test the statement as many times as I like. But I'm not sure what I'm talking about.

Comment: This was not intended as a criticism, just a way to think aloud about the (weak) law of large numbers and how using your own "experimental apparatus" could help to define confidence levels in either a frequentist framework or a bayesian one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are.

> If you tell me that "Dice have a 16.7% chance to roll a 1". I can test
> that statement to whatever confidence level I like.

Is the *classical* or *frequentist* probability, it is related to frequencies of events among all the possible events.

> But if you tell me that "There is a 20% chance of rain" or "There is a
> 45% chance Bill will be president" based on a model, I can't test
> that.

That’s the *subjective* probability, a measure of how strongly someone believes in something.

For more details check the [Interpretations of probability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/)  entry in the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*.

Comment: That link is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Tim, I believe the question pertains to mathematical probability versus inferential statistics. Would this be incorrect? I suspect you may be simplifying your answer to meet your audience, but I just wanted to make sure as I am also not a mathematician.

Comment: @Paze is there non-mathematical probability? "Probability that Bill will be president" cannot be stated in non-subjective manner. So I stand behind my answer.